# Classic Asp - Updating values to database if column ID exists and if not exists then adding that to database

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have a csv file that I need to add to database if ID value does not exist and if it does exist then i need to update it.

Example: 
1. if ID (CSV file) = 1 and ID(SQL database) = 1 , then in this case i need to update this row in database with data in the csv file.

2. if ID (CSV file) = 2 and ID(SQL database) = has no value of 2 in ID column, then in this case i need to add this row in database with csv column values.

I am successful in adding the row if ID (csv file) has no corresponding value in the table but unable to code on how to update the row if it exists.

Can any one help me with this.

Thanks!

Note: "rs" contains all the columns of the file and its values.

"rsAdd" contains all the columns of Database table(Merchants) and its values.

```
Set rs = GetRecordSet("C:\upload\new\" & TheNewFileName2)
    'Response.Write "No Errors"
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString="DSN=ABCD"
    cn.Open
    i = 0
        Set rsAdd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        rsAdd.CursorType=1
        rsAdd.LockType=3
        rsAdd.Open "Merchants", cn

        While Not rs.EOF
        rsAdd.AddNew

            For Each col in rs.Fields
                rsAdd(Replace(col.Name,"_","")) = col.Value
            Next
        rsAdd.Update
        rsAdd.Move 0        
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        If (i mod 100)=0 Or i=1 Then
            Response.Write i & ","
            If (i mod 2500) = 0 Then
                Response.Write "<br />"
            End If
        End If
    Wend

    rsAdd.Close
    Set rsAdd = Nothing
```

I have tried to do this but still no result.

```
While rs.EOF
            If rsAdd("MerchantId").Value = rs("Merchant_ID").Value Then
            rsAdd.Update            
            For Each col in rs.Fields               
                rsAdd(Replace(col.Name,"_","")) = col.Value
            Next

            Else 
            rsAdd.AddNew            
            For Each col in rs.Fields               
                rsAdd(Replace(col.Name,"_","")) = col.Value
            Next
            End If
        rsAdd.Update
        rsAdd.Move 0        
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
        If (i mod 100)=0 Or i=1 Then
            Response.Write i & ","
            If (i mod 2500) = 0 Then
                Response.Write "<br />"
            End If
        End If
    Wend
```

Comment: if I didn't have to worry about identity / auto-increment fields, I would run a sql statement that deleted the row (regardless if it existed), then do an INSERT of all of the data. This would prevent dupes from showing up.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery I am a little confused with what you said. I tried doing it in a different way. If you see above, I tried comparing ID and tried to update but it throws out an error at that If condition saying

ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: if you can get me the name of the ID column, I can provide you an example of what I was referring to